# How to create several plots if I have list of figures (or axis) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a function that create some plot:

```
def make_plot(x, y, lab_x=None, lab_y=None, title=None, err_y=None,
          interpolate_type='RBF', degree=None, smooth=True):
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf, InterpolatedUnivariateSpline, CubicSpline, BarycentricInterpolator
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
x1 = np.linspace(min(x) * 0.9, max(x) * 1.1, 400)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
plt.xlabel(lab_x)
plt.ylabel(lab_y)
plt.grid(True)
ax.errorbar(x, y, fmt='.', yerr=err_y, color='r', label=u'Data')
if smooth:
    X_plot = x1[:, np.newaxis]
    flag_model = False
    if interpolate_type == 'RBF':
        smth = Rbf(x, y)
    elif interpolate_type == 'IUS':
        smth = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
    elif interpolate_type == 'cubic':
        smth = CubicSpline(x, y)
    elif interpolate_type == 'polynomial':
        if degree == None:
            smth = BarycentricInterpolator(x, y)
        else:
            X = x[:, np.newaxis]
            degree = int(degree)
            import warnings
            warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", module="scipy", message="^internal gelsd")
            smth = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), LinearRegression())
            smth.fit(X, y)
            flag_model = True
    else:
        print 'Invalid interpolate type: You can choose RBF, IUS, cubic or polynomial'
        return
    if flag_model:
        y1 = smth.predict(X_plot)
    else:
        y1 = smth(x1)
    plt.plot(x1, y1, color='g', label=u'Smoth')
b1, a1, sig_b1, sig_a1 = leastsqr(x, y)
label_ = u'\nb={}±{}  a={}±{}'.format(np.round(b1, 3), np.round(sig_b1, 3), 
                                      np.round(a1, 3), np.round(sig_a1, 3))
ax.set_title(title)
plt.plot(x1, b1 * x1 + a1, label=u'Linear' + label_)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
return fig, ax
```

Actually doesn't matter what's happens inside. All I want is to apply this function several times and put all of the output plots in one axis. For example:

```
fig1, ax1 = make_plot(x1, y1)
fig2, ax2 = make_plot(x2, y2)
fig3 = plt.figure()  # and put first and second plot to third figure
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve. Can you be more specific about what the resulting plot should look like? You seem to be creating 3 figures, do you want the end up with only one figure at the end?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking: How much is "several times"? What is the data that you are passing to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matplotlib sanctioned way *[citation needed]* of writing a plotting function is to pass a reference to an `Axes` object to the function, which will be used to plot whatever you want, and then return a list of `Artists` created by your function

e.g.:

```
def my_plot(arg1, arg2, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    ret = ax.plot(arg1, arg2)  # replace with whatever you need here
    return ret

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
my_plot(x1,y1, ax=ax1)
my_plot(x2,y2, ax=ax2)
```

Comment: [citation] = https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles ?